# Which implementation is best for Prims algorithm , using Set or Prority Queue ? why?

Tags: algorithm, stl, set, priority-queue

I know about the implementation of both the data structures , i want to know which is better considering time complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both have same insertion and erase complexity `O(log n)`, while get min is for both `O(1)`.

A priority queue only gives you access to one element in sorted order ie, you can get the highest/lowest priority item, and when you remove that, you can get the next one, and so on. A set allows you full access in sorted order, for example, find two elements somewhere in the middle of the set, then traverse in order from one to the other.

In priority queue you can have multiple elements with same priority value, while in set you can't.

Set are generally backed by a binary tree, while priority queue is heap.

So the question is when should you use a binary tree instead of a heap?

In my opinion you should use neither of them. Check Binomial and Fibonacci heap. For prime algorithm they will have better performance.

If you insist in using one of them, I would go with priority queue, as it have smaller memory footprint and can have multiple elements with same priority value.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that Fibonacci heap will perform noticeably better than binary heap, and quite likely that it will perform worse. Whereas Fibonacci heap has excellent theoretical performance, binary heap and especially pairing heap outperform it in real world situations. Why? Because Fibonacci heap's asymptotic performance comes with a huge constant. Plus, it's difficult to implement. My recommendation would be binary heap to get it running, and Pairing heap if you think it needs optimization.

Comment: @JimMischel you are totally right, that is true, but I was thinking in custom implementation of both. Of course if you use already implemented heap structure it will be much faster than custom like Fibonacci heap.

Comment: Set can also have multiple elements with same priority value , as in case of Prims algo , we insert a pair in the Set . eg :- (0,1) and (0,5) can exist .

Comment: @RaviBhatt by the official docs you can't [see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

But if you put object and only one parameter in that object is responsible for priority and in your case you do than you could have (0,1) and (0,5).

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically speaking, both will give you an O(E log V)-time algorithm. This is not optimal; Fibonacci heaps give you O(E + V log V), which is better for dense graphs (E >> V).

Practically speaking, neither is ideally suited. Since `set` has long lived iterators, it's possible to implement a DecreaseKey operation, reducing the extra storage from O(E) to O(V) (the workaround is to enqueue vertices multiple times), but the space constant is worse than `priority_queue`, and the time constant probably is as well. You should measure your use case.

I will second Jim Mischel's recommendation of binary heap (a.k.a., `priority_queue`) -> pairing heap if the builtin isn't fast enough.